# Feller continuity of the stochastic kernel: compact set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

This question is an extension of [Feller continuity of the stochastic kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/feller-continuity-of-the-stochastic-kernel). Nate Eldredge provided a nice counterexample, but I failed trying to extend it to the compact set $B$.

The setting is the same: we are given a metric space $X$ with a Borel sigma-algebra, the stochastic kernel $K(x,B)$ is such that $x\mapsto K(x,B)$ is a measurable function and a $B\mapsto K(x,B)$ is a probability measure on $X$ for each $x$, i.e. $K(x,X) = 1$.

Let $f:X\to \mathbb R$. We say that $f\in \mathcal C(B)$ if $f$ is continuous and bounded on $B$.

Weak Feller continuity of $K$ means that if $f\in\mathcal C(X)$ then $F\in\mathcal C(X)$ where
$$
F(x):=\int\limits_X f(y)K(x,dy).
$$

I wonder if it implies that if $g\in \mathcal C(B)$ then 
$$
G(x):=\int\limits_Bg(y)K(x,dy)
$$
also belongs to $\mathcal C(B)$ for any compact set $B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try my previous counterexample, but with $B = [-10, -1/4] \cup [1/4, 10]$.