# Process with Feller stochastic kernel?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $m: \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^m) \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a probability measure.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be measurable, and continuous in the first argument.

Consider the process
$$ \begin{array}{rcl} X_{k+1} & = & f( X_k, Y_k ) \\ Y_{k+1} & \sim & m(\cdot) \end{array} $$
where $Y_{k+1}$ is an extraction of $m$, and $k = 0, 1, ...$.

I am wondering under which conditions on $m$ the above process has a [Feller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feller_process) stochastic kernel.

Comment. The notion of Feller stochastic kernel is also given here: [Feller continuity of the stochastic kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/feller-continuity-of-the-stochastic-kernel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example C.7 [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Discrete_Time_Markov_Control_Processes.html?id=NvPFQgAACAAJ) states that if $F:X\times Y\to X$ is a measurable function where $X$ and $Y$ are Borel spaces, with $F(\cdot,y)$ being continuous on $X$ for any fixed $y$, and $y_t\sim m$ where $m$ is arbitrary, then
$$
  x_{t+1} = F(x_t,y_t)
$$
is weakly (Feller) continuous Markov process. Your assumptions seem to fit, if I got what you meant by continuity in the first argument.

I also believe that the fact shall hold also for any topological space $X$ and any measurable $Y$, since the proof only uses the fact that $v(F(\cdot,y))$ is a continuous functions of $x$ whenever $v(\cdot)$ is, and the bounded convergence theorem.